# Puppet create link with timestamp only after Exec

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am working on a module to deploy tar file into directories on client. So whenever the tar file changes it deploys in to a new directory with datetime stamp like '20150204130312' . It works fine till this point. I am generating that date time stamp for directory in module.

Whenever the module runs the date and time are generated every time but the directory is only created if tar file updates which is fine. After this i want to create a link to that folder in which tar was extracted. I want that link to be created only if the tar file is extracted. But right now whenever puppet runs since the date and time stamp changes everytime the link is updated even if the tar was not extracted.

I tried using notify in exec and require on file resource but that doesnt work.
$dir have the timestamp generated on module using

```
$rel_dir= "/data/agrod/releases";
$dir= generate('/bin/date', '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
exec { "untar $targz":
    command => "/bin/mkdir -p $rel_dir/$dir/; /bin/tar xzvf /tmp/$targz -C $rel_dir/$dir",
    refreshonly => true,
    require => File["/tmp/$targz"],
   notify => File["/data/agrod/current"],    }

file { "/data/agrod/current":
 ensure => 'link',
 target => "/data/agrod/$dir",
 require => Exec["untar $targz"], 
}
```

How should i create the dependency so that link only gets created when tar file is extracted in exec. I dont want to use exec for creating links. I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `require` use `subscribe`:

```
exec { "untar ${targz}":
  command => "/bin/mkdir -p $rel_dir/$dir/; /bin/tar xzvf /tmp/$targz -C $rel_dir/$dir",
  refreshonly => true,
  subscribe => File["/tmp/${targz}"],
  notify => File["/data/agrod/current"]
}
```

The `subscribe` parameter will assume `require` automatically and will ensure the exec is only executed if the `File["/tmp/${targz}"]` resource changes.

Hope this helps